# Retain Cycles for Blocks Inside of Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Do I have to continuously declare weak references to break retain cycles for blocks inside of blocks?

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self setMyBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf doSomething];
    [strongSelf setMyBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        //do I need to create another weak reference to strongSelf for this block?
        [strongSelf doSomething];
    }];  
}];
```

Comment: blocks can use the scope of variables from function they are defined in, in your case you can use the weakSelf of outer block in the inner block, do not create the other weakSelf

Comment: By the way, you are doing the weak-strong dance wrong. You also need to test whether `strongSelf` is nil. In this case that makes no difference, but in general it's a good idea.

Comment: @matt what is the proper way to do the weak-strong dance?

Comment: You do not need to do the weak-strong dance for a block that is not retained by self directly or indirectly. –  An example of such a method is  the `NSArray` method `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid so.  `[strongSelf setMyBlock:<inner block>]` will cause `self` to retain the inner block.  If the inner block has a strong reference to `self`, that's a cycle.  The fact that the `strongSelf` variable was assigned *from* a `__weak` qualified variable originally does not make a difference.

As some other users mentioned, you can use the original `weakSelf` rather than creating a new one.  The reason you create a `strongSelf` reference in the block is that otherwise `self` might be deallocated while the block is running.  `strongSelf` will either end up `nil` (if `self` was deallocated before `strongSelf` was assigned, but this causes no harm) or else `self` will *not* be deallocated while the block is executing, because you have a strong reference.  During the time that you have a strong reference to `self`, the original `weakSelf` is *also* safe to use, because `self` will not be deallocated.